# Import Gitlab export (.tar.gz) to Bitbucket

Tags: gitlab, bitbucket

My company has a .tar.gz export from a repository they once had in GitLab. However, that repository is not accessible anymore. How do I import the exported file in a new Bitbucket repository?

Comment: Honestly I would just untar+unzip the archive, navigate to the top-level directory, and then set a new remote `origin` for the git repo. From there it'd be a `git push`. Sadly, if your export didn't include the git repository itself (the `.git` folder), then you've lost your repository's history and would need to remake it (adding in the files from the export).